# Can't access bios (even though I can access windows repair)

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, bios, fedora, grub

I have two HDD in my MSI laptop. In one of them Windows 10 (with its own efi partition) is installed. In the other one I tried installing Fedora (again, with its own efi partition in said hdd).

After installing Fedora, I cannot access Windows 10. But not only that, I cannot access the BIOS (DEL key in my system, and it worked before so I know I'm hitting the right key).

If I try turning on the laptop I just see the MSI logo and then a blank screen with an underscore on it.

If I press F3 I am able to enter the Windows recovering system. This means the keyboard is working.

None of the reset/restore options works: 
    - Reset your PC: Unable to reset your PC. A required drive partition is missing.
    - Refresh: There was a problem refreshing your PC. No changes were made
    - Startup repair: Startup repair couldn't repair your PC.
    - Opening a terminal in windows and using bootrec: doesn´t find windows installation.

However, if I (from the Windows Startup Menu) choose "Use a device" I can choose the second HDD and get the grub menu and I am able to boot Fedora. I've checked the Windows HDD and everything looks ok.

I am very confused. The fact that I cannot access the bios at all worries me and I don´t know what else I can do.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, did you try other keys instead of `DEL`, like `F2`, `F10`, `ESC` to access the BIOS? MSIs are normally `DEL` or `F2`